# Multiple wildcards in one query in elasticsearch

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, parseexception

```
curl localhost:9200/tweet/posts/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "and": [
      {
        "wildcard": {
          "_all": "*pet*"
        }
      },
      {
        "wildcard": {
          "_all": "*rom*"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

This gives me a parse exception. I want to run a MySQL `like(%test%)` type query with an AND condition. Is there any other good way to do in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe something like this?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "_all": {
              "value": "*pet*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "_all": {
              "value": "*rom*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if i have to run same query on selected fields instead of _all then how can i do that. I have to run search on these fields only ["name","address","contact","zip"].  Please help me.

Comment: I believe you then need to change the "must" to a "should" and then add one wildcard per field.  At least one "should" will need to match a record for it to be returned (if you have no must clause).

Answer (score 1):

dis_max query can support wildcard queries not a bool.
Please take a look here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html
I would write something like this:

```
{
 "query": {
     "dis_max": {
         "queries": [
               {"wildcard": {
                 "_all": {"value" : "*pet*"}
               }},
               {"wildcard": {
                 "_all": {"value" : "*rom*"}
               }}
           ]
     }
   }
}
```