# Opensearch Terms query wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm running the following opensearch query.

Sometimes I filter on a certain pname, sometimes I want to get all data for all pnames (i.e. no filter)

Rather than define two queries, one with the `terms` filter and one without it, I would like to have one query.

I thought I could pass in a `["*"]` for this, but that doesn't seem to work. All my pname's have a prefix as well p- so I also thought I could pass in `["p-*"]` but that also didn't work unfortunately.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "%s",
              "lte": "%s",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "pname.keyword": ["<wildcard to get all pnames?>"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a wildcard query. for e.g.

```
{
"size": 1000,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "gte": "%s",
                        "lte": "%s",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "pname.keyword": {
                        "value" : "p-*"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can I use multiple wilcard values when I want to match on say 2 pnames though? or a list of values here?
                "wildcard": {
                    "pname.keyword": {
                        "value" : ["pname1", "pname2"]
                    }
                }

Comment: For multiple matches that are not wildcards you can use the terms query. Pls see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583781/must-match-multiple-values#35594732  You can also add more than one wildcard query for the same field under a should (similar to OR condition) or must (AND condition)clause.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681478/multiple-wildcards-in-one-query-in-elasticsearch